# How to auto accept a call in WhatsApp?

Tags: automation, mobile-phone, whatsapp

Lets say I have a phone near but not enough to make a gesture or touch the device. I'm unable  to take the phone and push the buttons.

Certain contacts are safe enough, so I want to automatically answer a call from them after some number of rings/beeps.

Is there any script in Android or any configuration of the WhatsApp/system/other IM application that can do this?

I intend to speak in the call via the loudspeaker or a wireless headset.

Comment: I understand that you want this functionality, but I would highly discourage you from doing so, for (hopefully) obvious reasons...

Comment: Yeah, Im well aware of the potential implications, but for personal reasons Its something that fits certain situation.